# Formula for $\sqrt 2$ that bugged me with respect to irrationality

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

I was watching a very-introductory very-basic [minicourse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ks_A0B0IHUg) (in portuguese, unfortunately) about number theory. In the first minutes of lecture 1, the lecturer (a great one, btw) first defines what is an irrational number: it is a number that cannot be expressed as a quotient of two integers (aka it is not a solution for a polynomial equation of degree 1). Then he starts writing some formulas for $\sqrt 2$ (which would be later proved to be irrational): $$\sqrt 2 = \left(\frac{2\times 2}{1 \times 3}\right)\times\left(\frac{6\times 6}{5 \times 7}\right)\times\left(\frac{10\times 10}{9 \times 11}\right)\times\dots$$

What bugged and I obviously missed something is that this formula says that $\sqrt 2$ is *precisely* the quotient of two integers. I have no reason to believe that both $2\times2\times6\times6\times10\times10\dots$ is not an integer and the same goes for $1\times3\times4\times5\times9\times11\dots$.

Can anyone please explain what I got wrong about the formula or the theory?

Comment: What integer would that numerator be? There is no infinite integer.

Comment: "*I have no reason that both $2\times 2\times 6\times 6\times 10\times 10\cdots$ is not an integer*..."  You should have **every** reason to believe that it is not an integer.  The expression you describe is the limit of the results of all of those infinitely many multiplications of numbers greater than $1$ and is infinity.

Comment: Do not confuse "being a rational number" with "being the limit of a sequence of rational numbers."  Yes, $\sqrt{2}$ is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers, but that does not in and of itself mean that it is a rational number.  This is just like how $0$ is not a positive number but can be seen to be the limit of a sequence of positive numbers $1,.1,.01,.001,.0001,\dots$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the product of infinitely many elements from $\mathbb Q$ be irrational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2711754/can-the-product-of-infinitely-many-elements-from-mathbb-q-be-irrational)

Comment: On a side note: Shouldn't the second parenthesized factor have $5\times 7$ in the denominator, rather than $4\times 5$?  (The factor $\frac{36}{20}$ by itself is greater than $\sqrt{2}$, and as far as I can tell the other factors are each greater than $1$.)

Comment: Formula is fixed now. Thanks @paw88789.

Comment: Now I know my mistake: I didn't realize that the *product* of integers is actually a limit in disguise. Studying Wallis formulas and definitions makes it very clear that a ratio of infinite products can be irrational.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you see "...", you are looking at an abbreviation for a formal (and sometimes much longer) statement. What the formula means is that if $P(n)=\prod_{j=1}^n\frac {(4j-2)^2}{(4j-3)(4j-1)}$ whenever  $n\in \Bbb N,$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(n)=\sqrt 2.$

And $\lim_{n\to \infty}P(n)=\sqrt 2$ is itself an abbreviation for $\forall r>0\,\exists n_r\in \Bbb N\, \forall n\in \Bbb N\, (n\ge n_r\implies |P(n)-\sqrt 2|<r).$

Comment: Yes, that was the actual misunderstanding. Thank you for such a simple (yet profund) clarification.